# org.apache.catalina.connector.ClientAbortException: java.io.IOException: Broken pipe

Tags: jsf, tomcat, servlets

I'm using this code to download file from JSF page. When call this Java:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
                      "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
      xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets">

    <h:head></h:head>

    <h:body>
        <ui:composition>
            <title>example</title>
            <meta charset="utf-8"></meta>
        </ui:composition>
    </h:body>
</html>
```

**Bean:**

```
import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;
import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;
import javax.faces.view.ViewScoped;
import javax.inject.Named;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

@Named
@ViewScoped
public class Download implements Serializable {

    private String path = "/opt";
    private List<directoryListObj> dataList;
    private List<String> items = new ArrayList<>();
    private String zone;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        items.add("Select download mirror");
        items.add("USA");
    }

    public String downloadFile(String fileName) {
        try {
            FacesContext facesContext = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
            HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) facesContext.getExternalContext().getResponse();

            String reportPath = path + File.separator + fileName;
            File file = new File(reportPath);

            if (!file.exists()) {
                response.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_NOT_FOUND, "No file " + reportPath);
            }

            int DEFAULT_BUFFER_SIZE = 10240;
            response.setBufferSize(DEFAULT_BUFFER_SIZE);
            response.setHeader("Content-Length", String.valueOf(file.length()));    // Display file size during download
            response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\"" + fileName + "\"");

            BufferedInputStream bIn = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(file));

            int rLength = -1;

            byte[] buffer = new byte[1000];

            while ((rLength = bIn.read(buffer, 0, 100)) != -1) {
                response.getOutputStream().write(buffer, 0, rLength);
            }

            FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().responseComplete();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    public class directoryListObj {

        private String filename;
        private long size;
        private String lastModified;

        public directoryListObj(String filename, long size, long lastModified) {
            this.filename = filename;
            this.size = size / 1024;
            this.lastModified = new Date(lastModified).toString();
        }

        public String getFilename() {
            return filename;
        }

        public void setFilename(String filename) {
            this.filename = filename;
        }

        public long getSize() {
            return size;
        }

        public void setSize(long size) {
            this.size = size;
        }

        public String getLastModified() {
            return lastModified;
        }

        public void setLastModified(String lastModified) {
            this.lastModified = lastModified;
        }
    }

    public List<directoryListObj> getDataList() {
        dataList = new ArrayList();
        String files;
        File folder = new File(path);
        File[] listOfFiles = folder.listFiles();

        if (listOfFiles != null) {
            for (int i = 0; i < listOfFiles.length; i++) {
                if (listOfFiles[i].isFile()) {
                    files = listOfFiles[i].getName();
                    // Get the size
                    // Put discovered log files into the Array List
                    dataList.add(new directoryListObj(files, listOfFiles[i].length(), listOfFiles[i].lastModified()));
                }
            }
        }

        return dataList;
    }

    public String getZone() {
        return zone;
    }

    public void setZone(String zone) {
        this.zone = zone;
    }

    public List<String> getItems() {
        return items;
    }

    public void setItems(List<String> items) {
        this.items = items;
    }
}
```

**Web.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee
         http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
         version="3.1">

    <display-name>JavaServerFaces</display-name>

    <!-- Change to "Production" when you are ready to deploy -->
    <context-param>
        <param-name>javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE</param-name>
        <param-value>Development</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <resource-env-ref>
        <!-- Enable Weld CDI, also needs META-INF/context.xml entry -->
        <resource-env-ref-name>BeanManager</resource-env-ref-name>
        <resource-env-ref-type>javax.enterprise.inject.spi.BeanManager</resource-env-ref-type>
    </resource-env-ref>

    <!-- Skip comments in HTML code -->
    <context-param>
        <param-name>javax.faces.FACELETS_SKIP_COMMENTS</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <!-- Welcome page -->
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>faces/index.xhtml</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>

    <!-- JSF mapping -->
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <!-- Map these files with JSF -->
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/faces/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.jsf</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.faces</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

**Beans.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee
       http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/beans_1_1.xsd"
       bean-discovery-mode="annotated">
</beans>
```

**Content.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Context antiJARLocking="true" path="/tomcat-test">
    <Resource name="BeanManager"
              auth="Container"
              type="javax.enterprise.inject.spi.BeanManager"
              factory="org.jboss.weld.resources.ManagerObjectFactory"/>
</Context>
```

**faces-config.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<faces-config xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
              xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
              xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee
              http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-facesconfig_2_2.xsd"
              version="2.2">
</faces-config>
```

I get this stack trace printed into Tomcat log file:

```
org.apache.catalina.connector.ClientAbortException: java.io.IOException: Broken pipe
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.realWriteBytes(OutputBuffer.java:393)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.buf.ByteChunk.flushBuffer(ByteChunk.java:426)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.buf.ByteChunk.append(ByteChunk.java:339)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.writeBytes(OutputBuffer.java:418)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.write(OutputBuffer.java:406)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteOutputStream.write(CoyoteOutputStream.java:97)
    at com.web.common.Download.downloadFile(Download.java:70)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:247)
    at org.apache.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:267)
    at org.jboss.weld.util.el.ForwardingMethodExpression.invoke(ForwardingMethodExpression.java:40)
    at org.jboss.weld.el.WeldMethodExpression.invoke(WeldMethodExpression.java:50)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagMethodExpression.invoke(TagMethodExpression.java:105)
    at javax.faces.component.MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.invoke(MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.java:87)
    at com.sun.faces.application.ActionListenerImpl.processAction(ActionListenerImpl.java:102)
    at javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:315)
    at javax.faces.component.UIData.broadcast(UIData.java:1108)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:790)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:1282)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(InvokeApplicationPhase.java:81)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:198)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:646)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:291)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:219)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:142)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:617)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:518)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1091)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:668)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1521)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1478)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Broken pipe
    at sun.nio.ch.FileDispatcherImpl.write0(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.write(SocketDispatcher.java:47)
    at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.writeFromNativeBuffer(IOUtil.java:93)
    at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.write(IOUtil.java:65)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.write(SocketChannelImpl.java:471)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioChannel.write(NioChannel.java:127)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioBlockingSelector.write(NioBlockingSelector.java:101)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool.write(NioSelectorPool.java:173)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.InternalNioOutputBuffer.writeToSocket(InternalNioOutputBuffer.java:139)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.InternalNioOutputBuffer.addToBB(InternalNioOutputBuffer.java:197)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.InternalNioOutputBuffer.access$000(InternalNioOutputBuffer.java:41)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.InternalNioOutputBuffer$SocketOutputBuffer.doWrite(InternalNioOutputBuffer.java:320)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.filters.IdentityOutputFilter.doWrite(IdentityOutputFilter.java:84)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractOutputBuffer.doWrite(AbstractOutputBuffer.java:256)
    at org.apache.coyote.Response.doWrite(Response.java:503)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.realWriteBytes(OutputBuffer.java:388)
    ... 46 more
```

Looks like the mistake is into my code but I can't find it.

Do you have any idea where is the mistake?

I use Tomcat 8.0.23 with Mojarra 2.2.6. In firebug, I don't see errors.

Comment: My mistake. Here the complete output  http://pastebin.com/P86Xqder

Comment: Looks like the connection is being terminated by the client, or the timeout might have clicked at client's end.

Answer (score 9):

maybe your file is very large and you should increase the buffer size.
this worked for me:

```
System.out.println(response.getBufferSize());
response.setBufferSize(64*1024);
```

from: This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32345620/8430173)