# rse error: Exceeds depth limit for parsing

Tags: java, api, spring-boot, curl

I work with a Java and Spring Boot API that strangely provides some error which I think is not related to the code. I could be wrong though.

The POST operations are fine, but, this appears when I try to fetch some values with the GET operation. The code is provided below,

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/v1/users")
public class UserAPI {


    private UserService service;

    @Autowired
    public void setService(UserService service) {
        this.service = service;
    }

    // $ curl -i -X POST -H "Content-Type:application/json" -d "{ \"name\": \"Robert\", \"countryName\": \"Germany\"}" http://localhost:8080/api/v1/users/createUser
    // $ curl -i -X POST -H "Content-Type:application/json" -d "{ \"name\": \"Mary\", \"countryName\": \"USA\"}" http://localhost:8080/api/v1/users/createUser
    @PostMapping(value = "/createUser", consumes = "application/json", produces = "application/json")
    public ResponseEntity<User> createUser(@RequestBody @Valid User user) {

        service.save(user);
        return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.CREATED).body(user);
    }


    // $ curl -X GET http://localhost:8080/api/v1/users/findUserById?userId=1 | jq
    @GetMapping(value = "/findUserById")
    public ResponseEntity<User> findUserById(@RequestParam("userId") Long userId) {

        Optional<User> optional = service.findById(userId);

        if (!optional.isPresent()) {
            return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT).build();
        }

        User user = optional.get();

        return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.CREATED).body(user);
    }



 // $ curl -X GET http://localhost:8080/api/v1/users/findAllUsers | jq
@GetMapping("/findAllUsers")
public ResponseEntity<List<User>> findAllUsers() {

    List<User> users = service.findAll();

    if (users == null || users.isEmpty()) {
        return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT).build();
    }

    while (users.remove(null)) ;

    return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.CREATED).body(users);
}

}
```

The get the error in the terminal using the `cURL` command,

```
    $ curl -X GET http://localhost:8080/api/v1/users/findAllUsers | jq
      % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                     Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
    100  8058    0  8058    0     0  86422      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:-- 85723parse error: Exceeds depth limit for parsing at line 1, column 6479
    100 32610    0 32610    0     0   329k      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--  328k
    curl: (23) Failed writing body (0 != 8026)
```

In the same app, I also get the error provided below,

```
2019-03-16 18:40:52.263 ERROR 821 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost]           : Exception Processing ErrorPage[errorCode=0, location=/error]

org.apache.catalina.connector.ClientAbortException: java.io.IOException: Broken pipe
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.realWriteBytes(OutputBuffer.java:341) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.16.jar:9.0.16]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.flushByteBuffer(OutputBuffer.java:766) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.16.jar:9.0.16]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.append(OutputBuffer.java:671) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.16.jar:9.0.16]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.writeBytes(OutputBuffer.java:376) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.16.jar:9.0.16]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.write(OutputBuffer.java:354) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.16.jar:9.0.16]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteOutputStream.write(CoyoteOutputStream.java:96) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.16.jar:9.0.16]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.UTF8JsonGenerator._flushBuffer(UTF8JsonGenerator.java:2085) ~[jackson-core-2.9.8.jar:2.9.8]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.UTF8JsonGenerator._writeStringSegment2(UTF8JsonGenerator.java:1400) ~[jackson-core-2.9.8.jar:2.9.8]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.UTF8JsonGenerator._writeStringSegment(UTF8JsonGenerator.java:1347) ~[jackson-core-2.9.8.jar:2.9.8]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.UTF8JsonGenerator._writeStringSegments(UTF8JsonGenerator.java:1228) ~[jackson-core-2.9.8.jar:2.9.8]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.UTF8JsonGenerator.writeString(UTF8JsonGenerator.java:453) ~[jackson-core-2.9.8.jar:2.9.8]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.StringSerializer.serialize(StringSerializer.java:41) ~[jackson-databind-2.9.8.jar:2.9.8]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.MapSerializer.serializeFields(MapSerializer.java:722) ~[jackson-databind-2.9.8.jar:2.9.8]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.MapSerializer.serialize(MapSerializer.java:643) ~[jackson-databind-2.9.8.jar:2.9.8]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.MapSerializer.serialize(MapSerializer.java:33) ~[jackson-databind-2.9.8.jar:2.9.8]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.DefaultSerializerProvider._serialize(DefaultSerializerProvider.java:480) ~[jackson-databind-2.9.8.jar:2.9.8]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.DefaultSerializerProvider.serializeValue(DefaultSerializerProvider.java:400) ~[jackson-databind-2.9.8.jar:2.9.8]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectWriter$Prefetch.serialize(ObjectWriter.java:1392) ~[jackson-databind-2.9.8.jar:2.9.8]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectWriter.writeValue(ObjectWriter.java:913) ~[jackson-databind-2.9.8.jar:2.9.8]
    at org.springframework.http.converter.json.AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.writeInternal(AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.java:287) ~[spring-web-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.http.converter.AbstractGenericHttpMessageConverter.write(AbstractGenericHttpMessageConverter.java:103) ~[spring-web-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.AbstractMessageConverterMethodProcessor.writeWithMessageConverters(AbstractMessageConverterMethodProcessor.java:290) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.HttpEntityMethodProcessor.handleReturnValue(HttpEntityMethodProcessor.java:223) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.HandlerMethodReturnValueHandlerComposite.handleReturnValue(HandlerMethodReturnValueHandlerComposite.java:82) ~[spring-web-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:119) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:895) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:800) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1038) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:942) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1005) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:897) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:634) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.16.jar:9.0.16]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:882) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.16.jar:9.0.16]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.16.jar:9.0.16]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.16.jar:9.0.16]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:712) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.16.jar:9.0.16]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doInclude(ApplicationDispatcher.java:580) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.16.jar:9.0.16]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.include(ApplicationDispatcher.java:516) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.16.jar:9.0.16]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.custom(StandardHostValve.java:388) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.16.jar:9.0.16]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.status(StandardHostValve.java:253) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.16.jar:9.0.16]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.throwable(StandardHostValve.java:348) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.16.jar:9.0.16]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:173) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.16.jar:9.0.16]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.16.jar:9.0.16]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.16.jar:9.0.16]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.16.jar:9.0.16]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:408) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.16.jar:9.0.16]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.16.jar:9.0.16]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:834) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.16.jar:9.0.16]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1415) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.16.jar:9.0.16]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.16.jar:9.0.16]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628) ~[na:na]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.16.jar:9.0.16]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834) ~[na:na]
```

Can anyone see what is the issue here?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15785175/java-io-ioexception-broken-pipe

Comment: I have seen it earlier, but it doesn’t help.